# Как правильно реализовать регулярку для номеров

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Вот есть регулярное выражение
`^((8|\\+7|\\+380|\\+375|\\+373)[\\- ]?)?(\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[\\- ]?)?[\\d\\- ]{7,10}$`
пробую записать его в [оптимизатор регулярных выражений](https://easyregexp.ru/optimizer) но мне возвращает

> preg_match (): Ошибка компиляции: закрывающая скобка со смещением 36
> отсутствует.

Как вообще правильно строить регулярку?

Comment: `^((8|\+7|\+380|\+375|\+373)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярка для номеров РФ:

```
((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да это как-то и не особо ответ - в вопросе явно не только Россия. Да и регулярка лучше не стала по сравнению с вопросом.

Comment: "Раз посчитали за ответ, все норм" - нет, принятый ответ - это мнение только одного человека, и о качестве ответа ничего не говорит.

Comment: Вопросов нет, есть замечание: если автор ответа (в единственном числе) посчитал, что ваш вопрос решает его проблему, он может принять или не принять его. Принятие ответа совсем не означает, что ваш ответ лучший. Вы по факту везде пишете, "мой ответ приняли, значит он лучший" - нет, не значит.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вероятно, в оптимизатор надо совать не строку с дополнительным экранированием, а саму регулярку

   ```
   ^((8|\+7|\+380|\+375|\+373)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$
   ```
2. Он всё равно не работает, потому что говорит ошибку, хотя регулярка синтаксически корректная.
3. А смысл её оптимизировать?
4. Здесь не проверяется суммарное количество цифр в номере - вероятно, это баг.
5. Дефис экранировать обычно не требуется.